# Different time format returned by toLocaleTimeString

Tags: javascript, timestamp, timezone

I am using Javascript code such as that shown below, and recently found that while `Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString()` on one machine appends " GMT" or " BST" (depending on the time of year); on another machine, nothing is appended.

```
var m = new Date();
var time = m.toLocaleTimeString();
```

I use the returned string to create a log file, and would like the file names to have a canonical structure. I don't mind which of the two string formats is returned, as long as it is the same on both machines.

By the way, I also tried providing first and second arguments, such as `m.toLocaleTimeString('en-gb', { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit' })`, or `m.toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit' })`, but then the seconds are no longer included in the returned string.

Comment: What environment are these machines? Is this a browser or Node js? What versions?  Likely one has a version that supports Intl with ICU data present, and the other does not, but hard to say since you didn't provide much details.

Comment: Also, if you're making log files, a better idea would be to use `toISOString` so timestamps are in UTC rather than local time, and you won't have this concern at all.  `toLocaleString` and similar are generally for display to end-users.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom format function for your logs, using the Date.getHours(), getMinutes() etc.

This should be consistent across platforms and would allow any customization to be added easily.

```js
function formatTimestamp(date) {
    const hms = [date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds()];
    return hms.map(s => (s + '').padStart(2, '0')).join(':');
}

console.log('Timestamp:', formatTimestamp(new Date()));
```